# How to use std::format to create width and declare precision(in C++20)?

Tags: c++, format, c++20

I am trying to create a table using #include < format > in the C++20. However I do not know how to create a centre alignment of 17 and precision of 2 decimal places at the same time. I know width of 17 centre alignment would be simply: cout<<format("{:^17}",numb[i]) but how to output at 2 decimal places?

This is my code snippet:

```
      for (size_t k{};k<length;++k)
      {
    
    cout << "Enter the product number:\n";
    cin >> value;
    product.push_back(value);

    cout << "Enter the quantity:\n";
    cin >> value;
    quantity.push_back(value);

    cout << "Enter the unit price($):\n";
    cin >> value;
    price.push_back(value);

}

cout << "Product  Quantity  Perunit($)  Cost($)" << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < product.size(); i++)
{
    cout << format("{:<}{:^15}{:^7}{:^17.2}\n",product[i],
        quantity[i],price[i],(quantity[i]*price[i]));
}
```

I tried doing {:^17.2} but that does nothing(look at picture). Please give advice.
[image: 2 decimal places not shown!]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try including the `f` specifier (for floating-point numbers): `{:^17.2f}`